# How to delete a file from DB and several folders

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

So I have this:

- avatars

  - user1

    - avatar1.jpg
- covers

  - user1

    - avatar1.jpg
- media

  - user1

    - avatar1.jpg
- status

  - user1

    - avatar1.jpg

and this is what I have:

```
public function deletePhoto(){
        unlink(APPPATH . '/assets/img/users/avatars/user1/avatar1.jpg');
        unlink(APPPATH . '/assets/img/users/covers/user1/avatar1.jpg');
        unlink(APPPATH . '/assets/img/users/media/user1/avatar1.jpg');
        unlink(APPPATH . '/assets/img/users/status/user1/avatar1.jpg');
    }
```

Everytime I try to delete the avatar1.jpg file I can still see it in the folders.

Comment: what is your APPPATH ?

Answer (score -1):

maybe your path is not right, so add this lines to check if file exist.

```
 if (file_exists($path)) {   
      unlink($path);
    }else{
       ehco "File not found";    
    }
```